How can I use Chrome DevTools to test an Nginx proxy?
Background:
I have a service where people can get private in-browser remote desktop systems, and they'll get a specific port on my site allocated to them (e.g. mysite.com:8083 is session #3). However, in a lot of situations, my clients are behind a firewall that blocks all ports except :80, :443, :8080, & :8443, so they aren't able to access their sessions.
My solution to this was to create an Nginx proxy on port :443 (e.g. mysite.com/proxy/8083 proxies to mysite:8083). Due to the way this application works, I'm running, the Nginx config has to be a bit complicated and be able to handle different types of connections on different paths.
My question:
Is there some way that I can test this proxy using Chrome DevTools? Is there some sort of way to blacklist/whitelist specific URLs and ports, to simulate a firewall?
